# Translating a worded question into a linear equation system. 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A rower travels upstream at $6km/h$ and back to the starting place at $10km/h$. The total journey takes $48$ minutes. How far upstream did the rower go?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is goimg to fetch downvotes no efforts

Comment: sorry I'm not that smart but I tried to solve this by myself for a while and I still couldn't get an answer

Comment: It isnt solving but hust writing out steps here in tge bidy if the question

Comment: Could you help if you know how to solve it?

Comment: You need to solve further i would just give hints

Comment: I tried using d=st, and I've got ___ = 0.8(6x+10x) but don't know if I'm on the right track

Comment: I have given hints  you can use it then you have your answer

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be time upstream so dsitance upstream =$6x$ now $y$ be time taken travel downstream so distance  is $10y$ but dist upstream =downstream so $6x=10y$ and we know $x+y=\frac{4}{5}$ hrs solve and get the time. So rearranging (1) and dividing by $2$ we get $3x-5y=0$ and mutiplying x by $5$ we get $5x+5y=4$ so adding them we get $8x=4,x=1/2$ so $y=3/10$ so time is $30 minutes(up),18 minutes (down)$

Comment: I already got that but thank you for your help.

Comment: So do you need me to sove that

Comment: no that's ok I'll try to solve further by myself

Comment: See i have edited  it

Comment: Thank you for your help, next time I'll try to ask a smarter question.